# How to disable jenkins child process "irqbnc1"?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, redhat

A process "irqbnc1" is running on my server that is hogging high CPU utilisation. I checked and found that Jenkins is starting this process. This child process starts automatically if i killed this process forcefully. Even I am not able to find the binary of this process.

```
systemctl status jenkins
  ● jenkins.service - LSB: Jenkins Automation Server
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins)
  Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-06-10 16:06:49 IST; 1h 29min ago
  Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 32637 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 32696 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
       ├─ 5791 ./irqbnc1 -c hsjwj.conf
       ├─13265 sh
       ├─24222 sh
       └─32716 /etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=8080 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
```

top command output-

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                
5791 jenkins   20   0  370148   6976    524 S 300.0  0.0 147:59.75 ./irqbnc1 -c hsjwj.conf
```

Let me know the purpose of this process and how can i disable this process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That process is a bitcoin (cryptocoin) minning script.

You have a vulnerability in your Jenkins that allow an attacker to remote-execute code on your machine. The attacker created a script that downloads from an external source a JSON config file and a binary file. The binary file takes as an argument the config file and starts the mining process.

I would recommend to reinstall your OS + jenkins (latest versions).